# Как получить одну форму ModelForm из модели и связанной с ней (one-to-one) другой модели?

Tags: django

Как получить одну форму из модели и связанной с ней другой модели?

```
# models.py

from django.db import models

class BioInformation(models.Model):
    eyes_color = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    weight = models.IntegerField()
    height = models.IntegerField()

class Person(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    second_name = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    bio_info = models.OneToOneField(BioInformation, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

```
# forms.py

from .models import Person

class PersonForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Person
        fields = '__all__'
        labels = {
            'first_name': 'имя',
            'second_name': 'фамилия',
            'eyes_color': 'цвет глаз',
            'weight': 'вес',
            'height': 'рост'
        }
```

```
# views.py

from django.views.generic import FormView
from .forms import PersonForm

class PersonFormView(FormView):
    form_class = PersonForm
    template_name = 'board/auth_user_page.html'
    success_url = '/'
```

Например, в примере выше получается:
[image: результат]

А я хочу, что бы дополнительно к элементам для из модели `Person` отображались элементы для ввода из модели `BioInformation`, а не непонятный выпадающий список

Answer (score 0):

Возможно вам нужно воспользоваться фабрикой для связанных объектов.

```
>>> from django.forms import inlineformset_factory

>>> FormSet = inlineformset_factory(Person, BioInformation)
```

Док. http://djbook.ru/rel1.9/topics/forms/modelforms.html#inline-formsets